# Cortex M3 can't handle memset

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to build a simple project for Cortex M3. The problem I encountered with is that compiler includes a wrong libraries for the memset and other mem* -functions (memcpy, memcmp). And that results in hard fault every time when the execution approaches to the `memset(arr, 0x55, 10);`
in list file it is written like `blx <memset>`.
I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler. I don't use arm-none-eabi-ld for linking, but arm-none-eabi-gcc (**4.8.2**).

For gcc compiler I'm using these flags: `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -msoft-float -Os -gdwarf-2 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Wshadow -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`

For linker script I'm using these flags: `-L$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR) -L$(LIBGCC) --static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lnosys -Wl,--end-group -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -msoft-float -Wl,--print-gc-sections -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)` where 
$(LINKER_SCRIPT) is my own linker script
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR) - path to the libc.a, libnosys.a libraries
$(LIBGCC) - path to the libgcc.a library

**arm-none-eabi-gcc version is 4.8.2**

So, my question is: where could a possible problem? Why memset and other functions from the string.h don't work at all? Could you, please, tell me what I missed?

**Special section for dwelch ONLY:**
I can't provide you this code, because I do NOT have that toolchain anymore. You see, when you did ask me for the assembler, I've already recompiled a toolchain and got reed of that error. A new toolchain produces very different asm code, which does work. You wanted me to provide to you the thing that doesn't exist anymore. It's easy. The last thing, I catch was that blx instruction. Also, there are a lot of topics, where people complained about mem* functions. In those topics people typically had forgot to add architecture flags to linker

trust me, I've looked at this code for a very long time and I saw a lot of examples on network. Basically, it looked like: `08004c10 blx <memset> /*here was an error*/` Right now it looks like !!!`08004a14 BL <memset>`!!! And it works without any exceptions and hard faults. So, recompiling a toolchain was a solution. In this situation you are very wrong demanding a code which doesn't exist anymore and trying to say that I do not understand a problem.

**End of the special section #fordwelchonly**

Comment: Hmm.. you sure you are linking with the correct library set?  You specify -mthumb for interworking, but the call blx,<label> always causes a change to thumb mode...  Not at al lsure what's going on, but I'm betting that it's some ARM/thumb/interwork issue :(

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. I tried with and without both -mthumb and -mthumb-interwork. Result is still the same. Yes, I've read about this issue, but it seems there is no solution at the moment. Is it a gcc bug or I'm guilty as well?

Comment: please post the disassembly showing the problem.

Comment: I posted it; the cause of the problem was blx <memset> -line. Please, read Martin's comment and my answer below.

Comment: Code was written in C. The that was pointed by gdb is blx <memset>. Trust me, I understood the problem. Besides memset, use of any memset functions will result in crash. Moreover malloc and other stdlib's methods. If you want to say, that problem is not in toolchain, then, I guess, you don't understand the problem. You cannot solve the problem, if linker cannot find a proper libraries. Furthermore, Cortex M3 can be run in two states: ARM and thumb. Mine was run in thumb mode and for some reasons made a jump to the thumb state.

Comment: 2dwelch, your minus in my reputation means nothing. Once again, you can't solve this problem with simple re-writing a C code, cause there is nothing that could be re-written, my friend. If you think about wrong alignment, then you are wrong once again. It was checked and everything aligned as it suppose to be.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky blx label is none-conditional and can change state only to thumb according to the ARM documentation: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHFJFDG.html

Note
BLX label cannot be conditional. BLX label always causes a change to Thumb state.

Comment: @user1415536 Check [this one](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABDIIAG.html).

Comment: @dwelch I can't provide you this code, because I do NOT have that toolchain anymore. You see, when you did ask me for the assembler, I've already recompiled a toolchain and got reed of that error. A new toolchain produces very different asm code, which does work. You wanted me to provide to you the thing that doesn't exist anymore. It's easy. The last thing, I catch was that blx instruction. Also, there are a lot of topics, where people complained about mem* functions. In those topics people typically had forgot to add architecture flags to linker.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, then it depends on the situation. But still, Martin was right.

Comment: @dwelch trust me, I've looked at this code for a very long time. basically it looked like:

`08004c10      blx  <memset>     /*here was an error*/`

Comment: @dwelch trust me, I've looked at this code for a very long time and I saw a lot of examples on network. Basically, it looked like:

`08004c10      blx  <memset>     /*here was an error*/`
Do you know how does it looks right now?
!!!`08004a14     BL     <memset>`!!! And, oh, gods, it works without any exceptions and hard faults.
So, recompiling a toolchain was a solution. In this situation you are very wrong demanding a code which doesn't exist anymore and trying to say that I do not understand a problem.

Comment: You're wrong, Cortex-**M3** cannot be put into the ARM state. Only Cortex-R and Cortex-A series support ARM code. That's one reason why you should never see a `BLX <label>` instruction in the code for M3 (`BLX reg` can still happen).

Comment: @dwelch, I can't provide you a code that doesn't exist anymore. I do not collect broken builds. It is not that hard to understand. BTW, problem was already solved, when you asked for the info.

Comment: @dwelch, it's a bit strange, but reference manual stands only for thumb and debug states + thumb-2 instructions set. Thus I agreed with Igor.

Comment: Cortex-M3 processor implements the ARMv7-M architecture profile

Comment: and then the armv7-m reference manual shows the armv7-a, r and M differences right at the beginning (what Igor said).  "supporting only the Thumb instruction set".

Comment: this is bare metal basics, the more you do the more you understand that you need to control the compiler closer, find habits that work more often and are maintainable, and know the processors and peripheral nuances within a family...Not just ARM, pic, avr, mips, others have their own nuances.

Comment: @dwelch here is Igor's words conformation http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/ARM_Architecture_Overview.pdf it's not an official, but still.

Comment: when you dig into the manuals, esp the armv7-m instruction set reference you can see on an instruction by instruction basis what architecture is supported.  armv6-m added a few dozen thumb2 extensions to the thumb instruction set, armv7m added well over 100 if you take the time to count them...

Comment: My cut and pasting came straight from the horses mouth http://infocenter.arm.com

Comment: The next thing that folks get tripped up with (I still dont know if gcc/llvm have caught up) is that cortex-m3 and 4 are armv7m and cortex-m0 and m1 are armv6m significantly fewer instructions.  thumb without thumb2 extensions is the closest thing to a universal arm instruction set. beyond that you have to inspect the references to see what instructions are supported or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly an answer... but still. I had to re-build a toolchain. So, now everything looks as it suppose to be.
Before recompiling a toolchain the line, which did cause a hard fault looked like:

```
08004c10     blx     <memset>
```

After recompiling a toolchain this line of code is:

```
08004a14      bl      <memset>
```

Apparently, a toolchain was configured and built in a wrong way.

The closest thing to what I just did is this post: http://www.bengreen.eu/fancyhtml/techiestuff/createcrosscompiletoolchainforlpcmbed.html

If someone has a similar problem, please, check the link I posted above.

Added: Have a look at Martin's comment on the topic too. Martin was right about linked libraries.

Added: The reason why I cannot see the blx label in my code is simple - Cortex M3 doesn't have an arm state.  **Igor Skochinsky** pointed it out. Cortex M3 works only in thumb and debug states + implements thumb2 instructions set. Also, armv7m manual says that it works only in thumb states. That is, we have a reason, why it didn't work. Thank you Igor and Martin for the help.